# Which files are writable under /proc and why?

Tags: linux

I am trying to go deeper in Linux and when I was exploring /proc directory in root, there are some files that writable, as /proc is pseudo file system, so I don't understand why those files are writable??

Comment: what is significance of each "latency", "mtrr" some kind of registers are there, "timer_stats", "sysrq-trigger" under /proc.

Answer (score 2):

If a file is writable in `/proc` you can assume that by writing something meaningful into it you can tweak some behaviour of the kernel or trigger some action.

One example is the `/proc/sys/` subtree, which holds the variables accessible by `sysctl(8)` (actually, `sysctl(8)` just writes there).

See `proc(5)` manpage or [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) in the Linux kernel sources.

Answer (score 1):

The files in the `/proc` directory hierarchy contain information about your system hardware and the processes that are running on the system,

You can create Linux Kernel Modules within the `/proc` directory for the kernel to respond.

Theoretically you can create any file there, but most commonly these are used for the Linux Kernel Modules.

Those files are probably writable since they are re-spawned frequently.

Comment: K i got that point. I fired command "ls -l | grep w" on /proc and I found 3 Files **("latency", "mtrr" and "timer_stats")**, "sysrq-trigger" is 4th (which do not let write without sudo) and 3 link files  which are writtable, I searched for them but still not able to have clear understanding.