# Numerous world-writable Directories in /proc/

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-mint, file-permissions

I have searched for world-writable files and directories using the `find / -perm -2 ! -type l -ls` command on a Linux Mint system and have found a very large amount of world-writable files under `/proc/` and some in `/run/` and `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/`

Is this normal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which files are writable under /proc and why?](https://superuser.com/questions/728402/which-files-are-writable-under-proc-and-why)

Comment: Thank you @JoepvanSteen No, since I do not have files writable in /proc/ but only directories. But numerous of them are world-writable and not sure if this is normal.

Comment: How many of them are regular files (as opposed to e.g. sockets)?